# Permissions For Create a Team with Templates in Teams Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

Could someone shed ideas,

what's permission required to show like the below in the Teams App? Any ideas to enable approval for this one?

[image]

Comment: Your organization can restrict who can create teams. If you can't create a team or need to turn off team creation, check with your IT admin.

Comment: Can I know exactly what is the settings or permission?

Comment: Do you have tenant administrator or Teams administrator permissions?

Comment: Yes I do have permission

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict users who can create Teams to a group see here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/solutions/manage-creation-of-groups?view=o365-worldwide

As far as adding approvals, you may need to delegate a task or service desk ticket to IT for approval. I know there are Power Automate workflows or even spokes in ServiceNow that can automate creation upon approval.